# overwrite files created by emmbeded installer

Tags: installation, nsis

So I embedded two installers into my install script created with nsis, the whole thing is supposed to install one program then the other one, and then overwrite three files created by the second installer with newer versions. The problem is that those three files get created before the second installer gets to work. How can I make sure that these files get created only after the second installer finish it's job?

```
`

!include "MUI2.nsh"


; The name of the installer
Name "ADIS"

RequestExecutionLevel user

; The file to write
OutFile "ADIS.exe"
Unicode true
; The default installation directory
InstallDir "C:\ADIS"

 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH


 !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish"


 ;--------------------------------

 ; The stuff to install
 Section ""

  ; Set output path to the installation directory.
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR  

  RMDir /r $INSTDIR
 SectionEnd

 SectionGroup "instaladores"
 Section "Firebird"  
  ExecWait "Firebird\Firebird-2.5.4.26856_0_Win32.exe"

 SectionEnd

 Section "Cliente"a
  ExecWait "Cliente\setup.exe"
 SectionEnd

 SectionGroupEnd

 Section "Actualiza"
  ; Put file there
  ;File Nvo\ADIS.exe
  ;File Nvo\ADIS.ICO
  ;File Nvo\ADIS.GDB

  File /r "Nvo\*"


  SectionEnd`
```

Comment: Is a "Cliente\setup.exe" a NSIS installer? Did you create it?

Comment: No, "Cliente\setup.exe" is an old install suit of my software it´s not a NSIS installer, it was made in delphi

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run "Cliente\setup.exe" silently. Most installers have a silent switch you can use on the command line and some also provide a wait switch so you can wait even if the installer uses child processes.

What happens if you add a MessageBox before the file command and don't click it until the other installers have completed?

Comment: Thank you! that does the trick, the files are created only after the user clicks the ok button on the MessageBox. The only problem now is that not all users will wait until the installer is done  in order to click on the message. I tried to run "Cliente\setup.exe" like this `ExecWait "Cliente\setup.exe" /SP- /SILENT` but it gives my an error on compiling. I think it´s because it doesent supports silent mode. Got any sugestions in ordert to stop the files from being created before they are needed